# Channel From demanding title and URL title

Tags: safecracker

I have the simplest of channel forms and I am getting this error:

```
The form you submitted contained the following errors
    Title: This field is required.
    URL title: This field is required.
```

This is the striped down form:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="scholarship_apps" return="/x-test/ENTRY_ID/" logged_out_member_id="2"}
    <label for="title">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}"  ><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Next" class="button">    
{/exp:channel:form}
```

Guests can post entries. I've played with different parameters in the tag. I've hardcoded title and URL title fields. Always the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for hours and figure it out shortly after I post a question, of course. We have .htaccess code to force a trailing slash. That kills the channel forms.

Answer (score 0):

Channel form normally requires value for title and url_title fields when creating new entries.

You could add them both as hidden fields to pre-populate values so long as the url_title is unique.

Alternatively use the sample code in the docs https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channels/channel-form/examples.html

Normally I use this for new entries, where the URL title is hidden but gets populated by the `onkeyup` parameter in the title field:

```
<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" size="50" maxlength="100" onkeyup="liveUrlTitle(event);">
<input type="hidden" name="url_title" id="url_title" value="{url_title}" maxlength="75">
```